# Launch top with filters?

Tags: top

Is there a way to run top with these filters by default:

```
filters: '%CPU>0.0' + '!COMMAND=top'
```

?

Can I pass that via command line options?

Answer (score 3):

`top -i`

This option does exclude zombie and idle processes. And it sorts CPU usage greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

### `top:W` to save current view configuration

Using `W` command through `top` interactive CLI. For more details see [`man top` → Files](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/top.1.html#6.%20files).

An example, of the saved configuration:

**`more ~/.config/procps/toprc`** (Ubuntu 21.10)

```
top's Config File (Linux processes with windows)
Id:j, Mode_altscr=0, Mode_irixps=1, Delay_time=3.0, Curwin=0
Def fieldscur=�������ķ���&')*+,-./012568<>?ABCFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    winflags=2290996, sortindx=18, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=0, graph_mems=0, double_up=0, combine_cpus=0
    summclr=1, msgsclr=1, headclr=3, taskclr=1
Job fieldscur=�����(��Ļ�@<��)*+,-./012568>?ABCFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    winflags=193844, sortindx=0, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=0, graph_mems=0, double_up=0, combine_cpus=0
    summclr=6, msgsclr=6, headclr=7, taskclr=6
Mem fieldscur=���<�����MBN�D34��&'()*+,-./0125689FGHIJKLOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    winflags=193844, sortindx=21, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=0, graph_mems=0, double_up=0, combine_cpus=0
    summclr=5, msgsclr=5, headclr=4, taskclr=5
Usr fieldscur=�����������)+,-./1234568;<=>?@ABCFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    winflags=193844, sortindx=3, maxtasks=0, graph_cpus=0, graph_mems=0, double_up=0, combine_cpus=0
    summclr=3, msgsclr=3, headclr=2, taskclr=3
Fixed_widest=0, Summ_mscale=1, Task_mscale=0, Zero_suppress=0

begin: saved other filter data -------------------
window #0, osel_tot=2
    type=111,   filter=!COMMAND=top
    type=111,   filter=%CPU>0.0
end  : saved other filter data -------------------
```

**`~/.toprc`** (Ubuntu 18.04) `top` does not save or restore filters with `W` command. I don't know yet when it did change.

Comment: Hm, I tried that ... and it said `Wrote to ... .toprc`-- but then on next launch nothing was preserved.

Comment: @Dan which Ubuntu release do you have? Could you share the saved file though https://paste.ubuntu.com